# How to properly serialize bitmap in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, bitmap, deserialization

I have class `Texture`, that contains `System.Drawing.Bitmap Bitmap` and some additional data and methods. I want to serialize-deserialize it into binary file, so I implement `ISerializable` interface this way:

```
public Texture(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    PixelFormat pixelFormat = (PixelFormat)info.GetInt32("PixelFormat");
    int width = info.GetInt32("Width");
    int height = info.GetInt32("Height");
    int stride = info.GetInt32("Stride");
    byte[] raw = (byte[])info.GetValue("Raw", typeof(byte[]));

    IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(raw.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(raw, 0, unmanagedPointer, raw.Length);
    Bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, pixelFormat, unmanagedPointer);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
}

public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("PixelFormat", (int)Bitmap.PixelFormat);
    info.AddValue("Width", Bitmap.Width);
    info.AddValue("Height", Bitmap.Height);

    BitmapData data = Bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, Bitmap.PixelFormat);
    info.AddValue("Stride", data.Stride);
    byte[] raw = new byte[data.Height * Math.Abs(data.Stride)];
    Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, raw, 0, raw.Length);
    info.AddValue("Raw", raw);
    Bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

But after serialization and deserealization `Bitmap` looks corrupted. What did I do wrong? How to do it correctly?

Comment: You cannot call Marshal.FreeHGlobal() until *after* the bitmap is disposed.  Yes, that's very painful.  Instead of helping so much, consider using Image.Save() to save to a MemoryStream and serialize the bytes.  Load it again with a MemoryStream, don't dispose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Bitmap` class has the `SerializableAttribute`, so you can directly serialize a `Bitmap`. The appropriate code in your methods to serialize the bitmap are:

```
public Texture(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    Bitmap = (Bitmap)info.GetValue("Bitmap", typeof(Bitmap));
}

public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("Bitmap", Bitmap);   
}
```